# Ionic symlinked scripts can't compile

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic-project that have shared controllers and services with an external repository, placed outside of the Ionic root. To make it as simple as possible to maintain the controllers and services, I have symlinked the controllers and services folder to their respective folders in the external repository. This works fine during development in the browser, but when compiling for iOS I get an error

```
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/gildebrand/Desktop/App/Ionic/platforms/ios/www/js/controllers'
```

This isn't very strange, since the folder really doesn't exist at the specified path. It's only a symlink. A solution would be to copy the contents of the symlink source during build, but I don't know how to achieve that.

Anyone have any idea how to do this? I'm guessing this is more Cordova-related than Ionic-related.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode you can include scripts under Build Phases, which are running before the compiler is starting. Im using the following script:

```
cp -R /Users/YourUsername/Sites/mobileApps/georeminder/www/assets/ /Users/YourUsername/Sites/mobileApps/georeminder/platforms/ios/www/assets/
cp /Users/YourUsername/Sites/mobileApps/georeminder/www/index.html /Users/YourUsername/Sites/mobileApps/georeminder/platforms/ios/www/index.html
```

It is copying the root index.html and the assets folder where all js, css, images, … are living to the ios platform www folder.

Make the necessary changes, add a new build phase and it should work.